# $f(t) = u+th, u\in S^{n-1}$, then $h$ is perpendiocular to unit vector $\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}$ $\iff$ it's its velocity vector

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable path, with $f(t)\neq
>  0$ for all $t$. Calculate the velocity vector of the path
>   $\phi(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\phi(t) = \frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}$.
>   In the particular case of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$, given by
>   $f(t) = u+th$, with $u\in S^{n-1}$, $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$, calculate
>   $\phi'(0)$ and conclude that $h$ is perpendicular to the unit vector
>   $u$ $\iff$ it is the velocity vector $h = \phi'(0)$ of a path
>   $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to S^{n-1}$ with $\phi(0) = u$

First, calculating the speed vector, I'd simply do:

$$\phi'(t) = \frac{f'(t)}{|f(t)|} - \frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|^2}f'(t)$$

by the product and chain rule.

Now, for the particular case $f(t) = u+th \implies f'(t) = h$ we'd have:

$$\phi'(0) = \frac{h}{|u|}-\frac{uh}{|u|^2} = \frac{|u|h-uh}{|u|^2}$$

I must show that $\langle h,u\rangle = 0 \iff $ $h$ is the velocity vector $h = \phi'(0)$ of a path $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to S^{n-1}$ with $\phi(0) = u$

But I'm kinda lost here. To be a velocity vector, $h$ just needs to be the derivative of $\phi$? I can't see it this way. What about the other way, also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: The unit radial vector is normal to the tangent plane at $u$ say $T_uS^{n-1}$ and since we have $\phi'(0) \in T_u S^{n-1}$ then $ \phi'(0) \cdot u =0$. I'm guessing you'll get the result if you write out what this equation actually means. Let me know if you have a problem.